# Where do I ask about a specific piece of software?

Tags: discussion

I have an app on my windows tablet and I don't have a clue as to where to ask about about it so I'll start here and hope someone has an idea and migrates it.

Now, I am using the [Sparkiy](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/b06800e1-6a95-4d7b-9feb-32a371613afd?ocid=Apps_Search_WOL_en-us_search-main_search-results-from_search-Sparkiy_text-link_sparkiy) app on my tablet to code in Lua. It uses some kind of game framework and I couldn't figure out which one (there are dozens). The public wifi network I use blocks the site and I can't figure it out.

**Which game framework does it use?**